# How to have Regex Remove duplicate headers unsorted?

Tags: regex, sigil

I am converting a html website into an ebook using Sigil.
One project has 152 webpages added to a Sigil epub project.
Some other projects will have thousands of entries..  (we are starting with a small one)

The headers are workable but there are 3 books and maybe 5 chapters in each book and each chapter having 10 entries.

Each page has a header stating the book chapter and entry name.

We want to make a table of contents and then use RegEx to remove the duplicates keeping the first one.

An example of what the auto-generated TOC will look like before processing is:
(the indentation level will be a reflection of an header tag h1 h2 h3 that is unique)

```
  Book 1
     Chapter 1
         Entry 1
  Book 1
     Chapter 1
         Entry 2
  Book 1
     Chapter 1
         Entry 3
  Book 1
     Chapter 1
         Entry 4
  Book 1
     Chapter 1
         Entry 5
  Book 1
     Chapter 2
         Entry 6
  Book 1
     Chapter 2
         Entry 7
  Book 1
     Chapter 2
         Entry 8
```

Desired result (for 3 books not shown)

```
  Book 1
     Chapter 1
         Entry 1
         Entry 2
         Entry 3
         Entry 4
  Book 1
     Chapter 2
         Entry 5
         Entry 6
         Entry 7
         Entry 8
```

Comment: Someone edited this.. but I is not the desired output.  Please see history. I am new to this group and I'm afraid to change it back

Comment: @Worthwelle: I have renumbered the entries to be coherent between "before" and "after". Like this it's impossible to do the job, where does `Entry 4` come from? and what appens to `Entry 9`?

Comment: @Worthwelle: OP comment was posted 2019-08-13 07:46:56Z, I've made the edit on 2019-08-13 09:02:01Z, **after** his comment. That's not my edit OP has commented.

Comment: Thanks for putting back.  I have not made the opf file yet, but it will be vertical with new lines as shown.

Comment: I'm thinking it is not possible with RegEx and that a script will need to be used to find the first instance of an H1 and then delete all other instances with the same text inside.  Probably do it with js or libreoffice macro